# Angular MVC Routing with Custom Controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, angularjs-routing

I have an Angular MVC app that has couple of controllers. Default and another custom controller that I added.

`http://example.com/home/`

`http://example.com/ManageSummaryInfo/`

All my business logic lies with `ManageSummaryInfo` Controller.

```
 routes.MapRoute(                        
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ManageSummaryInfo", action = "HomePage", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

In Angular Routing, I have it like this,

```
$routeProvider.when('/showsummary',
                        {
                            templateUrl: 'ManageSummaryInfo/ShowSummary',
                            controller: 'ShowSummaryController'
                        });
    $routeProvider.when('/showerror',
                        {                            
                            templateUrl: 'ManageSummaryInfo/ShowError',
                            controller: 'ShowErrorController'
                        });   
    $routeProvider.when('/showplatform',
                        {
                            templateUrl: 'ManageSummaryInfo/ShowPlatform',
                            controller: 'ShowPlatformController'
                        });
```

My Views are also configured around `ManageSummaryInfo` Controller, but when I run I get to the home page, after which I click on one of elements should take me to the next page. But, I dont get routed and I got 404 - `The resource cannot be found.`error.

This is how my views look,

```
Views
--ManageSummaryInfo
----HomePage.cshtml
----Index.cshtml
----ShowSummary.cshtml
----ShowError.cshtml
----ShowPlatform.cshtml
```

My question, is when we have controllers in our route (ie, http://example.com/ManageSummaryInfo/- how would Angular route things and why mine getting file not found error.

I'm new to C# MVC Framework. Am I missing something related to ASP.NEt Routing ?Any help would be appreciated. I have tried to be eloborate, but if you would need more info, I'm happy to provide more code(Pastebin or something.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Adding Controller Class as per request,

```
public class ManageSummaryInfoController : Controller
    {
        // GET: ManageSummaryInfo
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult HomePage()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ShowPlatform()
        {
            return PartialView("ShowPlatform");
        }

        public ActionResult ShowSummary()
        {
            return PartialView("ShowSummary");
        }

        public ActionResult ShowError()
        {
            return PartialView("ShowError");
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does your menageSummaryInfoController look like?

Answer (score 0):

1)In the view(html code) on the link(a element) with the href showsummary (and the other also) add '#' before  'showsummary'.

2)Check you have

```
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js></script>
```

3)Check you have dependecy to ng-route :

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute']);
```

Angular routing work on html file only(not on chtml),so create html file instead.

```
var adminApp = angular.module('adminApp', ['ngRoute']);

adminApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/ar', {
            templateUrl: 'auto_responder.html',
            controller: 'arCtrl'
        }).
        when('/broadcast', {
            templateUrl: 'broadcast.html',
            controller: 'broadcastCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({

            redirectTo: '/ar'
        });
  }]);
```

Comment: I have added the references, Sir. Infact, When i hit the page directly, `http://example.com/ManageSummaryInfo/HomePage` and from there clicking on my DOM object that has href configured takes me to `http://example.com/ManageSummaryInfo/showsummary` page. How do i make it controller agnostic, like hit my `http://example.com/HomePage` and still take the action to my `ManageSummaryInfoController`  ?